# Python, program that multiplies number by 2 til it's greater than 1000, having issue with syntax

Tags: python, loops, nested

When I put oursum outside of the loop it infinitely multiplies it by 2

```
usernum=float(input('Enter a number: ')) 
if usernum<=0 or usernum>1000:              
    print('Your number is '+str(usernum))
else:
     oursum=usernum*2
     while oursum<=1000:
          print('Multiplied by 2 equals '+str(oursum))
```

When inside, it's not defined.

```
usernum=float(input('Enter a number: ')) 
if usernum<=0 or usernum>1000:              
   print('Your number is '+str(usernum))
else:

     while oursum<=1000:
          oursum=usernum*2
          print('Multiplied by 2 equals '+str(oursum))
```

I understand the problems I'm making but I don't know how to rectify this without making it unnecessarily long and complicated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're saving the result of the multiplication inside `oursum` but you're not using `oursum` later to continue multiplicating.
The following should work and it doesn't add complexity to the code:

```
usernum=float(input('Enter a number: ')) 
if usernum<=0 or usernum>1000:
    print('Your number is '+str(usernum))
else:
    oursum = usernum  # oursum starts from usernum and it will get bigger through each iteration
    while oursum<=1000:
        oursum=oursum*2
        print('Multiplied by 2 equals '+str(oursum))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second code, You are using `oursum` in the condition of the while statement before defining it. So, define `oursum` before the while loop and assign a value like 0

```
usernum=float(input('Enter a number: ')) 
if usernum<=0 or usernum>1000:              
   print('Your number is '+str(usernum))
else:
     oursum = 0 #like this
     while oursum<=1000:
          oursum=usernum*2
          print('Multiplied by 2 equals '+str(oursum))
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition in the `if` and `while` being pretty similar, you can combine both in a single test. It can also be a good idea to define a function in order to be able to reuse and test it more easily:

```
def transform(number):
    while 0 < number <= 1000:
        number *= 2
    return number


if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_num = float(input('Enter a number: '))
    print('After transformation, your number is', transform(user_num))
```

Comment: Thanks but what is meant by line 5?